# C/C++/C# Library for raster to vector conversion

Tags: raster, vector, software-recommendations, polygonize

I am looking for an "open source" C/C++/C# Library able to convert raster to vector data (Polygonize).
I know [gdal_polygonize.py](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_polygonize.html) is doing the job, but I can't use Python.
[Portrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/#downloading) is an other option, but first it is a tool (and not a Library) and second it is not focussed on GeoData.

Comment: [Portrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/#downloading) can output a geojson file, georeferncing can be done by the options X, L and B. [Example scrip](http://www.imagico.de/map/geotiff2shp.php).

Answer (score 4):

gdal_polygonize.py is based on the [gdal_polygonize()](http://www.gdal.org/gdal__alg_8h.html#a3f522a9035d3512b5d414fb4752671b1) function which doesn't require Python. So if you look at a library this would be my first choice.

Otherwise there are raster to vector writers in OTB library (but no app, as far as I know)

Comment: With [Potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/#downloading) the generalizing / smoothing level can be controlled very nicely. [gdal_polygonize()](http://www.gdal.org/gdal__alg_8h.html#a3f522a9035d3512b5d414fb4752671b1) goes simply around the pixels.